# shell script not working through cron but manually

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I'm using below command in a shell script:

```
echo "1" > log.txt  
if [ `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ":" -f 2 |  
awk {'print $1'}` = 'ipaddress' ] && [ `whoami` = 'userid' ]; then  
echo "2" >> log.txt  
crontab -l > Cron.txt  
echo "3" >> log.txt  
fi
```

The script runs fine when run manually but when scheduled through cron, it
stucks at this IF.

```
cron entry: 31 11 * * * /home/abc/cron_backup.sh
```

Output in log.txt   Manual run: prints 1,2,3 in log.txt   through
cron: prints 1 in log.txt

Comment: how do you run your command manually?

Comment: Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put as first line of your script the command interpreter line #! to make sure that sh will run it

after that, have you consider to use double bracket syntax [[ ]]?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "1" > log.txt  
if [[ `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ":" -f 2 |  
awk {'print $1'}` = 'ipaddress' ]] && [[ `whoami` = 'userid' ]]; then  
echo "2" >> log.txt  
crontab -l > Cron.txt
echo "3" >> log.txt  
fi
```

Comment: Isn't it better with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Thanks... I included #!/bin/sh, but still its not working from cron. what is the purpose of double bracket?

Comment: As the script is running successfully when run manually, there should not be syntax problem ... right. I have tried both #!/bin/bash and #!/bin/sh. Also double brackets [[ ]].

Comment: there should not be syntax problem except if you are not running with the same interpreter. Indeed, good way to know that is to run 'echo $SHELL' where you run successfully the script, and use that for #! setting (if different from what you tried before)

Comment: can there be any problem in the ",',` I have used. are the spaces around '|' okay.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the ifconfig, grep, cut awk and whoami calls. When you run it from the command line you have your profile, which has your PATH setting.

When it is run from cron, it does not have your profile. If you modify your PATH variable to point to the location of these programs then you wouldn't have that change when run from cron.

Try putting in the full path for the each of the commands and see it that makes any difference when run from cron.